# windows (7 / 10) installation hang on the logo and no spinning dots (old pc)

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I wanna install windows 7 / windows 10. when I boot with USB or DVD it hangs on windows logo and no spinning dots.
no error, no anything just hangs.
I clear CMOS, disable Quick boot, unplug floppy, etc.
It was useless.
and I check my ram, my CPU, my graphic card and my motherboard.
Everything is right.

information about my PC:

motherboard a8n5x (Asus 2005).

Cpu ADM Athlon (TM) 64 processor 3000+ 1.81 GHz.

ram 2 GB DDR 400.

graphic 6200TC PCI-E 128 MB DDR2.

I can install windows XP but can't install windows 7 or 10.
Please help me! );

Comment: Check the Asus site to see if there is a bios update available.

Comment: Bios updated in 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution!
I installed 2009 version of windows 7 - 32 bit (old version) and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

ASUS 2005 that runs XP.  The board may not support Windows 7 (looks like it does not) and certainly won't support Windows 10. You need a newer motherboard.

Comment: Are U sure? May not support Windows 7? Bios updated in 2007.

Comment: I am quite sure. I cannot find anything that says the old board will run Windows 7.  Windows 7 came out in July 2009 after this board was designed and after the last BIOS update